# Monitor Multiple Rails Applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, monitor

Are there any tools that I can run on my server to monitor multiple rails applications?

I need to monitor the number of requests each application receives, how much memory each application is using, how much of the cpu is being used and other stats similar to those. I need to see the stats for each individual rails application.

Comment: Here's a [monitoring tools comparison for Ruby on Rails](https://hixonrails.com/ruby-on-rails-tutorials/ruby-on-rails-application-monitoring/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recommend you try [NewRelic RPM](http://www.newrelic.com/get-RPM.html).

The free version:

> RPM Lite is the most widely used
>   solution for basic web application
>   monitoring. RPM Lite provides
>   application monitoring for unlimited
>   Java, Ruby or JRuby applications, for
>   unlimited users, for an unlimited
>   time. What a deal! With RPM Lite you
>   can identify overall app health, app
>   response time, throughput, Apdex SLA
>   scoring, cluster breakdown, and Notes.
>   You can also see where web
>   transactions are spending the most
>   time, isolate the worst offenders, and
>   determine where to focus your
>   remediation efforts

Later edit:

An alternative to NewRelic RPM is [ScoutApp](http://www.scoutapp.com/plugin_urls), that has a lot of plugins covering all your required features.

If you need something that can be run on your server, there is also the [munin plugins gem](http://github.com/barttenbrinke/munin-plugins-rails) that you may try. If you need a users monitoring tools (kind of like Google Analytics)m you can use the [RailStat](http://www.railstat.com/) gem.

Comment: As much as I don't particularly like recommending New Relic—their interface, when I last used it, was confusing to say the least—I don't know of anything else.

Comment: Is there anything I can run on my own server?

Answer (score 1):

The [Request Log Analyzer](https://github.com/wvanbergen/request-log-analyzer) gem can be useful, is free, and works by analyzing Rails log files. Thus, there's no chance of it having any negative impact on your application's performance.

Comment: Be careful when posting copy and paste boilerplate/verbatim answers to multiple questions, these tend to be flagged as "spammy" by the community.

Comment: Thanks for the warning, Kev. However, I wrote this answer myself, and it applies to both this question and the other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330991/response-time-and-server-health-monitoring-tools/7033960#7033960).