# Rails response time and server health monitoring tools

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 3 application running in production. What are the tools available in the market to monitor response time and server health.

I am aware of [New Relic](http://newrelic.com/web-app-monitoring-pricing.html) but response time monitoring is available only in gold version which is $200/month.

For monitoring the health of the system I know of [Server Density](http://www.serverdensity.com/metrics/).

Any other tool?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Monitor Multiple Rails Applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500761/monitor-multiple-rails-applications)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been using ServerDensity for one year and I'm extremely satisfied. Recently a GitHub user released a [Passenger plugin](https://github.com/cloudartisan/sd-passenger) for ServerDensity.

If you want something more Ruby-oriented, have a look at [Scout](https://scoutapp.com/).

Answer (score 1):

The [Request Log Analyzer](https://github.com/wvanbergen/request-log-analyzer) gem can be useful, is free, and works by analyzing Rails log files. Thus, there's no chance of it having any negative impact on your application's performance.